# How do I change the title in the navigation bar and the footer for Blazor Server Identity pages?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to change the title and the footer for the Identity pages in a Blazor Server App.
I've tried to scaffold Register and ManageIndex but I cannot find the section that needs to be changed. After scaffolding, no Layout.cshtml appears in the Shared folder.

[image: This title]

Answer (score 1):

This can be found in your server project `_Layout.cshtml`. For this project I just scaffolded the Login page only.

[image]